# Alternative to FindSiteMapNode

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, user-controls

Hi is there alternative to FindSiteMapNode

as atm I am trying to get Current node of a raw site but its returning null, even the security isn't enabled.

SiteMapNode currentNode = contentMapProvider.FindSiteMapNode("www.asdasdasda.com/asdsad.aspx");

however it works for

```
SiteMapNode currentNode = contentMapProvider.FindSiteMapNode(HttpContext.Current);
```

So looking for a alternative.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work by string is because you must create your own portal site map provider and override this function.

from msdn - "When overridden in a derived class, retrieves a SiteMapNode object that represents the page at the specified URL."

This means you must override the class and implement your own retrieval code. Here is a code example. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72b370ha.aspx Either way it implements using the current context.

Comment: I tired that before, but then it says can't find the method to override this method, but am not sure how i will overcome that error, cheers

Comment: exact words are  Error 1 'namespace.....FindSiteMapNode(string)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: my partial class is inheriting from : System.Web.UI.UserControl, not sure if i need to change it to something else or add another one

Comment: yes your class needs to inherit from the SiteMapProvider class not the usercontrol. This is the reason you can not find the class but implementing your own sitemap provider is out of the scope of this question honestly. I would strongly recommend you attempt to use the context if you can, that's what its there for.

Comment: I would Use Context, but problem is, I want to get sitemap of web from where I have been navigated e.g. in my case "Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()"